# Why console.log in node.js doesn't print array correctly while util.inspect does

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following two lines produce the following output:

```
console.log('arr:'+arr);
console.log('inspected arr:'+util.inspect(arr));
```

> arr:,testUser2
>   inspected arr:[ null, 'testUser2' ]

is it because it starts with a null value? it is very confusing that it doesn't even show up as an array.
it is in fact an array though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have `null` in array and when you say

```
"somestring" + array
```

it converts array to string using `toString()`, so `null` will be converted to `""`.

just try in browser console `[null,1,2].toString()` it will print `",1,2"`.

**While Util.inspect** returns a proper string representation of the object. Where it will print every thing as string something like `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: but if in the node shell I run console.log([null,'a']) it prints correctly

Comment: @arisalexis You're casting it to a string when you concatenate it.

Answer (score 2):

JS's occasionally-wat coercion rules.

Once you coerce it to a string the brackets go away, and a null value is represented by zero characters. `inspect` is the proper way to specify you want it to print out it's "natural" representation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the empty string when you try to print out the array if the value is null in the array is right as per specification in ECMAScript [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object)

when you try to concat the array like that, actually what you do is that you implicitly call the `toString` function in the array object which will call the `join` function in array object. And, in `join` spec, the function should check the `null` value, if `null` then it should return empty string.

This is taken from documentation.

> If element0 is undefined or null, let R be the empty String; otherwise, let R be ToString(element0).

in your case, I guess it will be much better to use `util.inspect()` as it does print more "pretty" information.